# adding a table to moodle database

Tags: moodle

I have some tables in moodle. how can I add a table in it?
I built my table in xmldbeditor first. Then, paste the php code in db/upgrade.php and change it's version to date (2012103000). finall I change version.php to that version.  But i think it isn't created. what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I usually back up the data in the tables I already have, uninstall the plugin and then go to the notifications page to install it again. Update.php **should** be called when you type in a new version number within version.php and then visit the notifications page, but when I am developing a plugin I tend not to rely on that.

Alternatively, load the table within the XMLDB editor on Moodle and click on the "[View SQL code]" link. This will generate SQL code which can be executed on PHPMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench to create the table directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create proper plugin for that the best place is local plugin folder.

if you creating a new plugin then you can add your tables in local/pluginname/db/install.xml

install.xml will only call when plugin is installed first time.

after that if want to change in structure then you need to put your code into db/upgrade.php and need to change the version and open admin/index.php